# Redirect only once using Cloudflare Worker

Tags: gatsby, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to implement a multilingual site in Gatsby and deploy it in Cloudflare pages. I am in need of a worker who will redirect to appropriate country-specific pages.

Ex: The URL to my site is example.com. If the user is visiting from India, I need it to redirect to example.com/in/. If from Japan, it should redirect to example.com/jp/.

I have written a Worker like below:

```js
const base = BASE_URL;
const statusCode = 301;

const getPrefix = (request) => {
    const countryCode = request?.cf?.country;
    const continent = request?.cf?.continent;
    let prefix = "";

    if (countryCode === "JP") {
        prefix = "/jp/";
    } else if (countryCode === "IN") {
        prefix = "/in/";
    }

    return prefix;
};

function handleRequest(request) {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    let { pathname, search, hash } = url;

    const prefix = getPrefix(request);
    if (prefix === "" || pathname.indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
        return fetch(request);
    }

    pathname = pathname.replace("/", prefix);
    const destinationURL = base + pathname + search + hash;
    return Response.redirect(destinationURL, statusCode)
}

addEventListener("fetch", async (event) => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});
```

With this, the redirection as mentioned above is happening correctly.

---

Additional **Requirement**

I am also in need of allowing users to view the Global site(example.com without any country-specific routes) if they wanted to. If the user clicks the hyperlink to visit the Global version of the site, the worker still redirects, which I do not want to happen.

**Or**, in other terms, **if already redirected, then the worker should not redirect anymore.**

*Restriction: cannot add another route say example.com/gb/ for the global version. It should be the root route itself.*

Is there any way to handle this requirement? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to check if the request includes a cookie. If the cookie is present, then you do not redirect. If the cookie is not present, you redirect and include the cookie in the response.

In this way, your code will only redirect once (or until the cookie is deleted).

There is an example for cookie parsing [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/extract-cookie-value)

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like a good idea. Could you please help me understand how to set a cookie when I redirect a request. (I want to add a cookie when I redirect for the first time so that on next hit, since cookie is present, redirection can be avoided).

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirect-plus-adding-cookies/125548/3) from the Cloudflare Community?